# How to get the currently executing tag of CucumberOptions?

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

My feature file is as follows :-
Feature: Login to HRM with multiple roles

@SMOKE_P1
  @REG_P3
   Scenario: SC1_SMOKE_P1: An sysadmin should login to HRM Portal
    Given Login To Application: User "sysadmin", Password: "sysadmin"

## And - Click on Login button

## Then  - Verify Msg: "Welcome ConfigAdmin" in Header

@SMOKE_P2
  @REG_P2
   Scenario: SC1_SMOKE_P1: An sysadmin should login to HRM Portal
    Given Login To Application: User "sysadmin", Password: "sysadmin"

## And - Click on Login button

## Then  - Verify Msg: "Welcome ConfigAdmin" in Header

I execute as clean test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @SMOKE_P1,@SMOKE_P2"

During execution I am retrieving scenario id as :-
ScenarioID = scenario.getName().substring(0, scenario.getName().length()); // +
        // "---:";;

```
    if (ScenarioID.contains(":")) {
        ScenarioID = ScenarioID.substring(0, ScenarioID.indexOf(":"));
        // ScenarioID.indexOf("\"") + 1,
    }

    StepDefinitionLogger.info("===============================");
    StepDefinitionLogger.info("My Scenario ID:" + ScenarioID);
    StepDefinitionLogger.info("Scenario Tags are: "+scenario.getSourceTagNames().toString());
    StepDefinitionLogger.info("===============================");
```

Since my Scenario has 2 tags from which only 1 is getting considered while executions. I want to retrieve the currently executing Tag.

Comment: So if you specify -Dcucumber.options="--tags `@tag1,`@tag2" and your feature only has `@tag2 then you want the intersection of the two sets?

Comment: We are setting the tags with an environment variable, thus we can get them via `System.getenv`

Answer (score 0):

probably a bit late but in case anyone is still wondering, here's how I achieved this:

- get the current Cucumberoptions Tags passed as command line -D argument:

```java
private String[] getTagsFromCmdParams() {
    String proptag = System.getProperty("cucumber.options");
    if(proptag != null && proptag.length() > 0) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("--tags (@[^ ]+(,@[^ ]+)*)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(proptag);
        boolean b = m.matches();
        if(b && m.groupCount() >= 2 ) {
            String test = m.group(1);
            if(test != null && test.length() > 0) {
                String[] bits = test.split(",");
                if(bits.length > 0) {
                    return bits;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return  new String[]{};
}
```

- get the current Cucumberoptions Tags from annotation (clazz being the `@CucumberOptions` annotated class)

```java
private String[] getTagsFromAnnotations(Class<?> clazz) {
    CucumberOptions co = clazz.getAnnotation(CucumberOptions.class);
    String[] tags = co.tags();

    if(tags.length == 1 && tags[0].contains(",")) {
        return tags[0].split(",");
    }

    return  new String[]{};
}
```

- Use both in this order

```java
public String[] getTags(Class<?> clazz) {
    String[] tags = this.getTagsFromCmdParams();
    if(tags.length > 0) {
        return tags;
    }

    return getTagsFromAnnotations(clazz);
}
```

- then using a hook, get the intersection between the scenario tags and option tags

```java
public static String[] getStringIntersection(String[] array1, String[] array2) {
    Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(array1));
    Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(array2));
    s1.retainAll(s2);

    return s1.toArray(new String[0]);
}

@Before
public void before(final Scenario scenario) {
    String[] scenarioTags = scenario.getSourceTagNames().toArray(new String[]{});
    String[] optionsTags = getTags(TestRunner.class); // TestRunner has the "@CucumberOptions" annotation
    String[] runningTag = getStringIntersection(scenarioTags, optionsTags);
    System.out.print("scenarioTags: ");
    printArray(scenarioTags);
    System.out.print("optionsTags: ");
    printArray(optionsTags);
    System.out.print("runningTag: ");
    printArray(runningTag); 
}
```

Hope this helps,

Cheers